# Terraform for_each iteration over object

Tags: amazon-web-services, foreach, terraform, amazon-route53

I'm relatively new to Terraform and I'm looking to simplify some private r53 zones I need to create using for_each.

I have the following local which I want to use to create private zones and associated A records in those zones:

```
locals {
  private_zones = [
    {
      name = "foo.com"
      txt = [
      "This is the txt record for foo.com"]
      ttl = 300
      records = {
        "host1" = "192.168.0.1",
        "host2" = "192.168.0.2"
      }
    },
    {
      name = "bar.com"
      txt = [
      "This is the txt record for bar.com"]
      ttl = 300
      records = {
        "host1" = "192.168.0.3",
        "host2" = "192.168.0.4"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I've found some code which will allow me to iterate over the local to create the zones

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "zone" {
  for_each = { for name in local.private_zones : name.name => name }
  name     = each.value.name

  vpc {
    vpc_id = <vpc_id>
  }
}
```

but I've no idea how I can iterate and create A records in the respective zone using the records list in each local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use [aws_route53_record](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route53_record) and **flattened** `private_zones`:

```
locals {
    private_zones_flat = merge([
        for zone in local.private_zones: {
            for host, ip in zone.records:
                "${zone.name}-${host}" => {
                    zone_name = zone.name
                    host = host
                    ip = ip
                }
        }
    ]...)
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "host" {
  for_each = local.private_zones_flat
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.zone[each.value.zone_name].zone_id
  name    = each.value.host
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = [each.value.ip]
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated, once I understood that the ]...) was actually part of the merge ;)